# How do I edit the source files of a c++ project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I know this seems like a strange question, but apparently the answer isn't a simple as "Open it in Visual Studio and edit it".

I have an idea for [this project](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb), and I would like to try my hand at implementing it.

Despite appearances, I do have a background in programming, just not much in c++. I do a lot of .Net stuff day to day (C# and F#). I can read c++, pretty comfortable editing it, and can even write something simple from scratch!

Anyway, in .net things are simple. You have a solution, which contains a bunch of projects, and when you build it you get a exe or dll out the other side.

In this project, there seems to be a 2 step process. First I used cmake to prepare a VS2019 solution, then (secondly) I can open that solution in Visual Studio and build it to get the exe.

However, the solution that results from the first step does not seem to contain the source code. Specifically, [this is the file](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/blob/master/src/function/scalar/sequence/nextval.cpp) I am interested in playing around with. But it does not appear in the cmake results.

I could open the file and edit it before the cmake step, but then Visual Studio does not understand the context of the code and it is basically just a text editor at that point.

So how do I edit this file in a project in Visual Studio, and have all the benefit of VS knowing how this small piece of code fits into the whole project?

Comment: @PaulSanders the file I care about has a bunch of includes referring to some *.hpp files. All I need are those files in the project, right? (there was a comment by Paul Sanders when I wrote this reply)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused when you say that cmake builds a Visual Studio solution / project file (.sln / .vcxproj).  That is not normally the way; for most open source projects you have to construct a VS project yourself, if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, cmake makes a .sln, then in VS I can build to get an exe. But the sln does not contain the same source files as in the main part of the repo.

Comment: I'm confused.  If the VS project is correctly building the appropriate .exe file then it must, by definition, contain the source files that the .exe needs.  It might help to know that there is a distinction between .sln (solution) and .vcxproj (project) files.  Project files know how to build things, and therefore contain all the relevant source file references.  Solution files are a collection of one or more project files and merely serve to group project files together.

Comment: And that is how it works in .net too. But here, when I navigate to the src folder (created by cmake) related to the file I care about, I see a cpp file with a single line of code: "#include <C:/repos/duckdb/src/function/scalar/sequence/nextval.cpp>"

Comment: Hmmm, no idea, sorry.  You could consider raising an issue on the github repo.

Comment: I think I have found the answer: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/UNITY_BUILD.html

Comment: Looks promising, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is used to build the project, that is compile and link the needed files to make the executables/libraries. As with many open source projects, you are left to your own devices to use it in an IDE. This has the advantage every contributor can use their own prefered environment. It has the disadvantage that it can be a little complicated to set up. But the source files are just that - they are source files. You could edit them in Notepad if you want. C++ doesn't have a concept of "projects" or "solutions". Those are workflows your IDE (Visual Studio) imposes on you.

Comment: That make sense. But if I wanted a rich IDE experience to edit this file (as opposed to the Notepad experience), I can get that with VS but making a project and/or solution and adding the files that are related to the file I care about, right?

Comment: @ChechyLevas Yes, you are right. But I would recommend that you use the building instructions in the Readme to build it instead of the Visual Studio integrated commands. Those depend on a lot of settings that you would have to set right, whereas CMake in this case is configured out of the box.

Comment: The readme instructions say to use cmake. But cmake gives a source file with a single line of code: #include <C:/repos/duckdb/src/function/scalar/sequence/nextval.cpp>

Comment: So the original file is not really there, just a link to it.

Comment: @ChechyLevas I don't understand. The instructions are pretty clear. What do you mean "cmake gives a file"? You should clone the GIT repo, open a terminal in the folder you cloned it to and run `make`. That will build everything. If you make changes to any source files, the build will include those changes.

Comment: The problem is that it was cmake-ing using this setting: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/UNITY_BUILD.html
which doesn't really lead to source files that friendly to work with, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ChechyLevas But you shouldn't work with any source files CMake generates. Those are intermediate files. You should edit the files that are in the Git repo.

Comment: Ok understood. So I know which file I want to edit, but when I edit it, I want my IDE to understand what the references to the other parts of the code base "mean" so that I can peak definitions and use other IDE magic. So to do that I must create a brand new project, and reference the source files (in the repo) that are relevant. right?

Comment: @ChechyLevas I would suggest creating an "Open Folder" project, like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=msvc-160 (or choose an IDE that doesn't make things so unnecessarily complex)